# How to make an Application Insights kusto query sort correctly on performanceBucket?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics

Is there a way to make an Application Insights kusto query sort on `performanceBucket` 'correctly', i.e. on bucket duration? When I summarize or sort using performanceBucket and don't specify a sort I get something like this (note for example that 1-3sec is not adjacent to 3-7sec):

[image]

If I add a sort by performanceBucket it's done alphanumerically:

[image]

I want it to be in this order (or the reverse of it)

- <250ms
- 250ms-500ms
- 500ms-1sec
- 1sec-3sec
- 3sec-7sec
- 7sec-15sec
- 15sec-30sec
- 30sec-1min
- 1min-2min

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to artificially add a column that indicates your preferred sorting order, then sort by it, and project it away:

```
// Synthetic data - don't copy this
let YourResult = datatable(perfBucket:string, count_:long) [
    "250ms-500ms", 14000,
    "7sec-15sec", 600,
    "1sec-3sec", 9700
];
// This is the actual query
YourResult
| extend sortOrder =
    case(perfBucket == "<250ms", 1,
         perfBucket == "250ms-500ms", 2,
         perfBucket == "500ms-1sec", 3,
         perfBucket == "1sec-3sec", 4,
         perfBucket == "3sec-7sec", 5,
         perfBucket == "7sec-15sec", 6,
         perfBucket == "15sec-30sec", 7,
         perfBucket == "30sec-1min" ,8,
         perfBucket == "1min-2min", 9,
         10)
| order by sortOrder asc
| project-away sortOrder
```

Result:

| perfBucket | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 250ms-500ms | 14000 |
| 1sec-3sec | 9700 |
| 7sec-15sec | 600 |